# Motion layout prevents update on recyclerview

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

I have started using motion layout for some top bar scrolling, and looks like there is an issue that prevents recycler view from showing updated data. Currently I am using `2.0.0-alpha3` of `ConstraintLayout`. In the view I have toolbar and 2 tabs that act as filter, lets say `filterX` and `filterY` those pass some rx stuff that basically just filters list of items based on the `type` this is not important because data is filtered properly, thread is correct, data is passed to adapter every time, but when I do scroll my motion layout to top or bottom, from time to time the changes are not reflected in recycler view, they reload after I scroll it a little bit or even touch, its not happening in case of standard `ConstraitLayout`. Have anyone experienced this and know any solution?

Edit: Layout with motion layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/scene_month">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_back"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        style="@style/ActivityTitle"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar" />

    <com.example.FilterView
        android:id='@+id/filter_view'
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/filter_view" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

And motion scene

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        app:constraintSetEnd="@id/end"
        app:constraintSetStart="@id/start">
        <OnSwipe
            app:dragDirection="dragUp"
            app:touchAnchorId="@id/recycler"
            app:touchAnchorSide="top" />
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint android:id="@id/title"
            android:text="@string/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
            android:fontFamily="@font/rubik_medium"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar">
            <CustomAttribute
                app:attributeName="textSize"
                app:customFloatValue="28"/>
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint android:id="@id/title"
            android:text="@string/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
            android:fontFamily="@font/rubik_regular"
            android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
            <CustomAttribute
                app:attributeName="textSize"
                app:customFloatValue="20"/>
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```

Comment: Please show us your layout and MotionScene so we can help you.

Comment: Made an edit with the code

Comment: I am having the same issue in `constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha4`. When I do `notifyDatasetChanged` the data doesn't get updated. It updates when I perform a scroll

Comment: True, I updated and it even got worse, before it was working for the first load, now even first load of data is struck until scroll is performed

Comment: Looks like `alpha5` fixed all the issues, however I did just a fast test right now so there could be some situations in which it is failing

Comment: I was experiencing the same issue in alpha 4. Updated to beta 1 and the issue is gone for me as well.

Comment: @user2141889 any solution ?

Comment: @JithishPN update motion layout to latest version, the issue is resolved

Comment: @user2141889  constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta1  i m using this one. Still  some issues with scroll

Answer (score 5):

By following the possible solution as discussed here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130386093

adding the tag motion:layoutDuringTransition="honorRequest" to the Transition fixed the issue

Example:

```
<Transition
    android:id="@+id/myTransition"
    motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
    motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
    motion:layoutDuringTransition="honorRequest"
    motion:motionInterpolator="linear">
    <OnSwipe
        motion:dragDirection="dragUp"
        motion:onTouchUp="stop"
        motion:touchAnchorId="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        motion:touchAnchorSide="top" />
```

besides that, can also try to update to newer version, in my case, I'm currently using

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta08'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0-alpha05'
```

Note: layoutDuringTransition tag only available with beta04 version of constraint layout and above

Comment: `motion:layoutDuringTransition="honorRequest"` made it to work. Updating versions didn't help though, tried up to latest non-stable versions of ConstraintLayout (2.1.0-alpha2), RecyclerView(1.2.0-beta01) and ViewPager2(1.1.0-alpha01).

Answer (score 3):

`RecyclerView.scrollBy(0, 0)` as temporary workaround.

Link to these Google Issue Tracker

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130386093
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130862165

Comment: In my case `recyclerView.smoothScrollBy(0,1)` helped.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason `RecyclerView.scrollBy(0, 0)` didn't work for me. I am scrolling the whole motion layout to top using below method when there are updates to recyclerView.

`motionLayoutView.transitionToStart()`

Comment: I found out that you actually need to scroll it and maybe in an animated manner, so in my case smooth scrolling by 1 pixel helped - `recyclerView.smoothScrollBy(0,1)`. Ugly, but works.

Answer (score 0):

update to newer version

```
  implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta7'
```

as they fixed that problem as listed with release notes

- Nested scroll view issues in MotionLayout
- Transition listener issues with MotionLayout
- Memory leak in MotionLayout
- RecyclerView performances
- Group visibility
- Padding issues

https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2020/06/constraintlayout-200-beta-7.html

Answer (score 0):

None of these workarounds worked for me. I gave up on fixing these and I was fixing other UI bugs I had. I have several views sliding up/down and hiding/showing.

I was using `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(...)` in my code and it wasn't inside a `Runnable`. After wrapping it in `view.post{}` like this the problem disappeared:

```
view.post{
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition()
}
```

This may seem irrelevant but I suggest checking your code to see if the problem is somewhere else. Like everyone else I thought this is caused by `MotionLayout` because when I swapped it with `ConstraintLayout` it worked fine.